# github,eclipse and android

Tags: android, eclipse, git, github

I'm new to git. I want to create a new project with Eclipse, and use Github to manage it.

The problem is, Github suggested me to add a .gitignore file to let it ignore files in bin, but once I did that, there is a new master in the Github's repository.

Then when I tried to push my project, it said:

```
To git@github.com:Benjaminz/SocialEventPlanner
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:Benjaminz/SocialEventPlanner'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

When I ran pull it said:

```
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details

git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master
```

What mistake did I make? How to correct this?

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that ur poject is not stashed 
Do Below Steps :

```
git stash
git pull
git stash pop
```

Answer (score 0):

For the second error message, you can type:

```
git branch -u origin/master master
```

Then try again your `git pull`.